# How do I test that zerolog logger raised log event of type error?

Tags: unit-testing, go, zerolog

In my Go app I moved error logging into a separate function

```
package logging

import "github.com/rs/zerolog"

func LogError(logger zerolog.Logger, err error) {
    logger.Error().Err(err).Msg("")
}
```

and want to create a small test to ensure the error log event was been raised. For reproduction purposes I won't show the test file but code from the playground https://go.dev/play/p/Jnyz51JemTh

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
)

func main() {
    logger := zerolog.Nop()
    testError := errors.New("test error")
    logHook := &logHook{}

    logger.Hook(logHook)

    LogError(logger, testError)

    amountOfLogEvents := len(logHook.logEvents)

    fmt.Printf("Expected amount of log events: 1\nActual amount of log events: %v", amountOfLogEvents)

    // TODO inspect logHook.logEvents[0]
}

func LogError(logger zerolog.Logger, err error) {
    logger.Error().Err(err).Msg("")
}

type logHook struct {
    logEvents []zerolog.Event
}

func (logHook *logHook) Run(logEvent *zerolog.Event, level zerolog.Level, message string) {
    logHook.logEvents = append(logHook.logEvents, *logEvent)
}
```

You should see the output

> Expected amount of log events: 1

> Actual amount of log events: 0

I thought I could create a custom hook to catch the event and inspect it. Unfortunately I'm struggling with two things

- Inspecting the error, message, ... from a single `zerolog.Event` didn't work for me. I couldn't find any fields or functions for this
- The test fails because `amountOfLogEvents` is empty, although I would expect it to have one event

Do you know what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Nop` cant apply the hooks,And the `Logger` is not a pointer

```
// Nop returns a disabled logger for which all operation are no-op.
func Nop() Logger {
    return New(nil).Level(Disabled)
}
// Hook returns a logger with the h Hook.
func (l Logger) Hook(h Hook) Logger {
    l.hooks = append(l.hooks, h)
    return l
}
```

2. For the same reason, Your `logHook` should be

```
func (logHook *logHook) Run(logEvent *zerolog.Event, level zerolog.Level, message string) {
    logHook.logEvents = append(logHook.logEvents, *logEvent)
}
```

So we get this and can pass the test, see [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/thr8pePuQbX)

```
logger := zerolog.New(os.Stdout)
logHook := &logHook{}
logger = logger.Hook(logHook)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I fixed my code. Unfortunately the test didn't pass :/

Comment: I updated my question with a reproducible playground example

Comment: @baitendbidz Hi, I re-edited the answer and I did miss one thing. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another similar approach could be to use your own `io.Writer` to gather log messages as strings. It may be a bit easier to compare them later with string values expected by the test.

```golang
func TestMyTest(t *testing.T) {
    logs := &logSink{}
    logger := zerolog.New(logs)

    testedComponent := NewComponent(logger)
    testedComponent.DoSomething()

    assert.Contains(t, logs.Index(0), "some error logged here")
}

type logSink struct {
    logs []string
}

func (l *logSink) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    l.logs = append(l.logs, string(p))
    return len(p), nil
}

func (l *logSink) Index(i int) string {
    return l.logs[i]
}
```

After each logged event, the `logSink.logs` slice will contain a string for each entry like:

```
[
   {"time":"...","level":"info","message":"..."},
   {"time":"...","level":"debug","message":"..."},
]
```